# Как разобраться с функцией pow?

Tags: c++, функции

Запускаю задачку, но не могу понять вытекающую из неё проблему. Как решить и понять?

В коде:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float F(float x, float y, float z);

int main(){
    float x,y,z,b,k,P;
    x=6.5;
    b=8/9;
    k=4.5;
    P = tan(F(x,b,k))+cbrt(F(k,pow(b,2),x))-pow(F,2)(b + 0.1,k,pow(x, 2));
}

float F(float x, float y, float z){
    float f;
    f = pow(x,2)-pow(y,2)+z;
    return f;
}
```

Возникает проблема в данной строке:

```
    P = tan(F(x,b,k))+cbrt(F(k,pow(b,2),x))-pow(F,2)(b + 0.1,k,pow(x, 2));
```

Консоль говорит:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:11:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘pow(float (&)(float, float, float), int)’
   11 |     P = tan(F(x,b,k))+cbrt(F(k,pow(b,2),x))-pow(F,2)(b + 0.1,k,pow(x, 2));
      |                                                    ^
```

Comment: Что вычисляет выражение `pow(F,2)`?

Comment: Почему в `tan(F(x,b,k))` вы поставили после `F` список аргументов, а в `pow(F,2)` - нет?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, думаю там было написано `F^2(параметры F)`. :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Угу, похоже на то...

Comment: Следующая проблема: `8/9` - это ноль.

Answer (score 1):

В строке:

```
P = tan(F(x,b,k))+cbrt(F(k,pow(b,2),x))-pow(F,2)(b + 0.1,k,pow(x, 2));
```

один из вызовов `std::pow` является `pow(F,2)`, где `F` - это вовсе не число, а функция:

```
float F(float x, float y, float z);
```

Передать ее напрямую в `std::pow` не получится, да и бессмысленно.

Я подозреваю, что это опечатка, и планировалось вызвать: `pow(F(XXX),2)`, где `XXX` - это аргумент к `F()`.
Определитесь, с тем, что есть `XXX` в вашем вычислении.